# How to solve an overdetermined system of equations?

Tags: linear-algebra, systems-of-equations

I'm trying to solve an overdetermined system of five equations and four variables, but I'm not being successful in this task. I have the following unknowns, $F,G,K$ and $L$, and I need to solve $F$ and $L$ in terms of $G$ and $K$, that is

$$
F(G,K) \,\, ,\\
L(G,K) \,\, .
$$

The system that I'm treating is the following:

$$
F + G = H + J \,\, ,\\
i F \omega -i G \omega =i H \sqrt{\omega ^2-V_0}-i J \sqrt{\omega ^2-V_0} \,\, , \\
H e^{i a \sqrt{\omega ^2-V_0}}+J e^{-i a \sqrt{\omega ^2-V_0}}=K e^{i a \omega }+L e^{-i a \omega } \,\, , \\
i H \sqrt{\omega ^2-V_0} e^{i a \sqrt{\omega ^2-V_0}}-i J \sqrt{\omega ^2-V_0} e^{-i a
   \sqrt{\omega ^2-V_0}}=i K \omega  e^{i a \omega }-i L \omega  e^{-i a \omega } \,\, , \\
K e^{i b \omega }+L e^{-i b \omega }=0 \,\, , \\
$$
where the constants $a,b \in \mathbb{R}$. How could I Solve this system?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici Sorry, I've Misspelled the system, now It's correct!

Comment: I see 5 equations and 6 variables ?

Comment: Yes, indeed, that is it!

Comment: If the system is of maximal rank then you will only have one free variable and the remaining 5 will depend on this chosen variable. If the rank is 4 then you will have 2 free variables and the remaining 4 depending on those etc... You should look in linear algebra of how to solve $Ax=0$ with $A$ an $n$ by $m$ matrix.

Comment: If a system is overdetermined, you just need to solve it regularly, and then check that the solutions found satisfy the remaining equations.

Comment: You also have $H$, $J$, $V_0$ and $\omega$. What are they, and is $\omega^2>V_0$?

Comment: $H$, $J$ and $V_{0}$ are real constants and $\omega \in \mathbb{C}$.

Comment: Which constants are permitted in the equations F(G,K) and L(G,K)?

Comment: $\omega, a, b$ and $V_{0}$!

Comment: @DavidQuinn $\omega \in \mathbb{C}$, so there is no way to compare with $V_{0}$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For each equation list the variables with the ones you want to keep left of a separator (|) and the unwanted variables or constants on the right.

1.(F,G|H,J)

2.(F,G|H,J)

3.(K,L|H,J)

4.(K,L|H,J)

5.(K,L|)

You want (F,G,K|) and (L,G,K|)

Note equation 5 is already in the form (L,K|) or as a function L(K).

To find (F,G,K|) you need equations 1 and/or 2 to get F but with H and J eliminated.

To isolate H and J combine equation 5 with 3 and 4 respectively to get rid of L.

Note equations 3 and 4 are linearly independant in H and J, the +/- sign difference.

5+3 -> 6.(K|H,J) , new equation 6

5+4 -> 7.(K|H,J) , new equation 7

Equations 6 and 7 are 2 linearly independent equations with respect to 2 unknowns H and J so H and J can be isolated.

6+7 -> 8.(K|H) and 9.(K|J) the two new equations 8 and 9.

Substitute 8 and 9 into 1 (or 2) to replace H and J by K to get (F,G,K|).

---

Running these instructions in maxima

```
E1 : F + G - H - J;
tex(%th(1));
E2 : F*w - G*w - H*sqrt(w^2-Vo) + J*sqrt(w^2-Vo);
tex(%th(1));
E3 : H*exp(i*a*sqrt(w^2-Vo)) + J*exp(-i*a*sqrt(w^2-Vo)) - K*exp(i*a*w) - L*exp(-i*a*w);
tex(%th(1));
E4 : H*sqrt(w^2-Vo)*exp(i*a*sqrt(w^2-Vo)) - J*sqrt(w^2-Vo)*exp(-i*a*sqrt(w^2-Vo)) -K*w*exp(i*a*w) + L*w*exp(-i*a*w);
tex(%th(1));
E5 : K*exp(i*b*w) + L*exp(-i*b*w);
tex(%th(1));

L5 : solve(E5,[L]);
tex(%th(1));

E53 : subst(L5,E3);
tex(%th(1));
E54 : subst(L5,E4);
tex(%th(1));

EHJ : solve([E53,E54],[H,J]);
EHJ[1][1];
tex(%th(1));
EHJ[1][2];
tex(%th(1));

EF : subst(EHJ[1],E1);
tex(%th(1));
```

---

Gives the results with equations all equal to zero.

$$-J-H+G+F$$

---

$$\sqrt{w^2-{\it Vo}}\,J-\sqrt{w^2-{\it Vo}}\,H-w\,G+w\,F$$

---

$$-e^ {- a\,i\,w }\,L-e^{a\,i\,w}\,K+e^ {- a\,i\,\sqrt{w^2-{\it Vo}}}\,J+e^{a\,i\,\sqrt{w^2-{\it Vo}}}\,H$$

---

$$w\,e^ {- a\,i\,w }\,L-w\,e^{a\,i\,w}\,K-\sqrt{w^2-{\it Vo}}\,e^ {- 
 a\,i\,\sqrt{w^2-{\it Vo}} }\,J+\sqrt{w^2-{\it Vo}}\,e^{a\,i\,\sqrt{w
 ^2-{\it Vo}}}\,H$$

---

$$e^ {- b\,i\,w }\,L+e^{b\,i\,w}\,K$$

---

Answer for L(K):

$$\left[ L=-e^{2\,b\,i\,w}\,K \right] $$

---

$$e^{2\,b\,i\,w-a\,i\,w}\,K-e^{a\,i\,w}\,K+e^ {- a\,i\,\sqrt{w^2-
 {\it Vo}} }\,J+e^{a\,i\,\sqrt{w^2-{\it Vo}}}\,H$$

---

$$-w\,e^{2\,b\,i\,w-a\,i\,w}\,K-w\,e^{a\,i\,w}\,K-\sqrt{w^2-{\it Vo}}
 \,e^ {- a\,i\,\sqrt{w^2-{\it Vo}} }\,J+\sqrt{w^2-{\it Vo}}\,e^{a\,i
 \,\sqrt{w^2-{\it Vo}}}\,H$$

---

$$H=-{{\left(\left(\sqrt{w^2-{\it Vo}}-w\right)\,e^{2\,b\,i\,w}+
 \left(-\sqrt{w^2-{\it Vo}}-w\right)\,e^{2\,a\,i\,w}\right)\,e^{-a\,i
 \,\sqrt{w^2-{\it Vo}}-a\,i\,w}\,K}\over{2\,\sqrt{w^2-{\it Vo}}}}$$

---

$$J=-{{e^ {- a\,i\,w }\,\left(\left(\sqrt{w^2-{\it Vo}}+w\right)\,e^{
 2\,b\,i\,w}+\left(w-\sqrt{w^2-{\it Vo}}\right)\,e^{2\,a\,i\,w}
 \right)\,e^{a\,i\,\sqrt{w^2-{\it Vo}}}\,K}\over{2\,\sqrt{w^2-
 {\it Vo}}}}$$

---

Answer for F(G,K):

$${{\left(\left(\sqrt{w^2-{\it Vo}}+w\right)\,e^{2\,b\,i\,w}+\left(w-
 \sqrt{w^2-{\it Vo}}\right)\,e^{2\,a\,i\,w}\right)\,e^{a\,i\,\sqrt{w^
 2-{\it Vo}}-a\,i\,w}\,K}\over{2\,\sqrt{w^2-{\it Vo}}}}+{{\left(
 \left(\sqrt{w^2-{\it Vo}}-w\right)\,e^{2\,b\,i\,w}+\left(-\sqrt{w^2-
 {\it Vo}}-w\right)\,e^{2\,a\,i\,w}\right)\,e^{-a\,i\,\sqrt{w^2-
 {\it Vo}}-a\,i\,w}\,K}\over{2\,\sqrt{w^2-{\it Vo}}}}+G+F$$

---

The extra equation 2, can be used to eliminate G and create a function F(K).

maxima code:

```
EF2 : subst(EHJ[1],E2);
tex(%th(1));

EFK : solve([EF,EF2],[G,F]);
tex(%th(1));
```

---

$$-{{\left(\left(\sqrt{w^2-{\it Vo}}+w\right)\,e^{2\,b\,i\,w}+\left(w
 -\sqrt{w^2-{\it Vo}}\right)\,e^{2\,a\,i\,w}\right)\,e^{a\,i\,\sqrt{w
 ^2-{\it Vo}}-a\,i\,w}\,K}\over{2}}+{{\left(\left(\sqrt{w^2-{\it Vo}}
 -w\right)\,e^{2\,b\,i\,w}+\left(-\sqrt{w^2-{\it Vo}}-w\right)\,e^{2
 \,a\,i\,w}\right)\,e^{-a\,i\,\sqrt{w^2-{\it Vo}}-a\,i\,w}\,K}\over{2
 }}-w\,G+w\,F$$

---

$$G=-{{\left(\left(\left(2\,w\,\sqrt{w^2-{\it Vo}}+2\,w
 ^2-{\it Vo}\right)\,e^{2\,b\,i\,w}+{\it Vo}\,e^{2\,a\,i\,w}\right)\,
 e^{2\,a\,i\,\sqrt{w^2-{\it Vo}}}+\left(2\,w\,\sqrt{w^2-{\it Vo}}-2\,
 w^2+{\it Vo}\right)\,e^{2\,b\,i\,w}-{\it Vo}\,e^{2\,a\,i\,w}\right)
 \,e^{-a\,i\,\sqrt{w^2-{\it Vo}}-a\,i\,w}\,K}\over{4\,w\,\sqrt{w^2-
 {\it Vo}}}}$$

$$F=-{{\left(\left({\it Vo}\,e^{2\,b\,i\,w}+\left(-2\,w
 \,\sqrt{w^2-{\it Vo}}+2\,w^2-{\it Vo}\right)\,e^{2\,a\,i\,w}\right)
 \,e^{2\,a\,i\,\sqrt{w^2-{\it Vo}}}-{\it Vo}\,e^{2\,b\,i\,w}+\left(-2
 \,w\,\sqrt{w^2-{\it Vo}}-2\,w^2+{\it Vo}\right)\,e^{2\,a\,i\,w}
 \right)\,e^{-a\,i\,\sqrt{w^2-{\it Vo}}-a\,i\,w}\,K}\over{4\,w\,
 \sqrt{w^2-{\it Vo}}}}$$

---

Make the computer do the work.

---

To get L(G,K):

Solve 3.(K,L|H,J) + 4.(K,L|H,J) to isolate H and J to get equations:

10.(K,L|H) and 11.(K,L|J)

Then combine 1.(F,G|H,J) + 2.(F,G|H,J) to remove F.

12.(G|H,J)

Then substitute H and J from 10 and 11 into 12 to get 13.(G,K,L|)

---

The maxima instructions:

```
EHJ2 : solve([E3,E4],[H,J]);
EHJ2[1][1];
tex(%th(1));
EHJ2[1][2];
tex(%th(1));

EF3 : solve(E1,F);
tex(%th(1));

EnoF : subst(EF3,E2);
tex(%th(1));

EL2 : subst(EHJ2,EnoF);
tex(%th(1));

ELGK : solve(EL2,[L]);
ELGK[1];
tex(%th(1));
```

---

$$H={{e^{-a\,i\,\sqrt{w^2-{\it Vo}}-a\,i\,w}\,\left(\left(\sqrt{w^2-
 {\it Vo}}-w\right)\,L+\left(\sqrt{w^2-{\it Vo}}+w\right)\,e^{2\,a\,i
 \,w}\,K\right)}\over{2\,\sqrt{w^2-{\it Vo}}}}$$

$$J={{e^ {- a\,i\,w }\,\left(\left(\sqrt{w^2-{\it Vo}}+w\right)\,e^{a
 \,i\,\sqrt{w^2-{\it Vo}}}\,L+\left(\sqrt{w^2-{\it Vo}}-w\right)\,e^{
 a\,i\,\sqrt{w^2-{\it Vo}}+2\,a\,i\,w}\,K\right)}\over{2\,\sqrt{w^2-
 {\it Vo}}}}$$

---

$$\left[ F=J+H-G \right] $$

---

$$w\,\left(J+H-G\right)+\sqrt{w^2-{\it Vo}}\,J-\sqrt{w^2-{\it Vo}}\,H
 -w\,G$$

---

$$w\,\left({{e^ {- a\,i\,w }\,\left(\left(\sqrt{w^2-{\it Vo}}+w
 \right)\,e^{a\,i\,\sqrt{w^2-{\it Vo}}}\,L+\left(\sqrt{w^2-{\it Vo}}-
 w\right)\,e^{a\,i\,\sqrt{w^2-{\it Vo}}+2\,a\,i\,w}\,K\right)}\over{2
 \,\sqrt{w^2-{\it Vo}}}}+{{e^{-a\,i\,\sqrt{w^2-{\it Vo}}-a\,i\,w}\,
 \left(\left(\sqrt{w^2-{\it Vo}}-w\right)\,L+\left(\sqrt{w^2-{\it Vo}
 }+w\right)\,e^{2\,a\,i\,w}\,K\right)}\over{2\,\sqrt{w^2-{\it Vo}}}}-
 G\right)+{{e^ {- a\,i\,w }\,\left(\left(\sqrt{w^2-{\it Vo}}+w\right)
 \,e^{a\,i\,\sqrt{w^2-{\it Vo}}}\,L+\left(\sqrt{w^2-{\it Vo}}-w
 \right)\,e^{a\,i\,\sqrt{w^2-{\it Vo}}+2\,a\,i\,w}\,K\right)}\over{2
 }}-{{e^{-a\,i\,\sqrt{w^2-{\it Vo}}-a\,i\,w}\,\left(\left(\sqrt{w^2-
 {\it Vo}}-w\right)\,L+\left(\sqrt{w^2-{\it Vo}}+w\right)\,e^{2\,a\,i
 \,w}\,K\right)}\over{2}}-w\,G$$

---

Answer L(G,K):

$$L={{\left({\it Vo}\,e^{2\,a\,i\,\sqrt{w^2-{\it Vo}}+2\,a\,i\,w}-
 {\it Vo}\,e^{2\,a\,i\,w}\right)\,K+4\,w\,\sqrt{w^2-{\it Vo}}\,e^{a\,
 i\,\sqrt{w^2-{\it Vo}}+a\,i\,w}\,G}\over{\left(2\,w\,\sqrt{w^2-
 {\it Vo}}+2\,w^2-{\it Vo}\right)\,e^{2\,a\,i\,\sqrt{w^2-{\it Vo}}}+2
 \,w\,\sqrt{w^2-{\it Vo}}-2\,w^2+{\it Vo}}}$$

---

Comment: Tanks, your answer were awesome, just another doubt, Can I get $L(G,K|)$?

Comment: @Wayner Klën : I added the L(G,K), cheers.